# Django celery is not starting

Tags: django, django-celery

```
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,355: WARNING/MainProcess] self.client.info()
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,355: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 437, in info
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,356: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.execute_command('INFO')
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,357: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/home/vsinghal/workspace/meditred1/eggs/kombu-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/kombu/transport/pyredis.py", line 344, in execute_command
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,357: WARNING/MainProcess] conn.send_command(*args)
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,358: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 299, in send_command
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,358: WARNING/MainProcess] self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,359: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 281, in send_packed_command
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,359: WARNING/MainProcess] self.connect()
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,359: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 226, in connect
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,361: WARNING/MainProcess] sock = self._connect()
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,361: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 238, in _connect
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,361: WARNING/MainProcess] sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,362: WARNING/MainProcess] File "<string>", line 1, in connect
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,363: WARNING/MainProcess] TypeError
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,364: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2012-10-09 03:45:45,364: WARNING/MainProcess] coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

I am not getting whats getting wrong. I am getting the above message while starting the celery

Comment: Format the log to something more readable.

Comment: Seems like you have either host or port set to None

Comment: show us the celery config you have in settings.py

Comment: have you installed broker server like rabbit mq

Comment: Issue solved. Thanks to asksol issue was exactly the same